# What should I do if somebody answers my question in the comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer

My problems are solved thanks to an answer in the comments. I also would like to provide official recognition by accepting this answer, but I can't.

Comment: I sometimes answer in comments, because, although my comment *does* answer the question, it's not high enough quality to be a "real" answer. Someone should do something about this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is nothing much you can do except asking the user if he is willing to provide the comment as an answer so that you can upvote and accept it. In the end, it is the user's decision.

Sometimes, especially with high-reputation users, they might suggest you write the answer yourself using the solution in their comments. That is not so unusual and a good way for you to get some points. So don't be shy.

Comment: And should you feel uncomfortable taking the credit for yourself, there is precedence for [using community-wiki answers](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/322/7167).